# Replace javascript syntax with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain why this replacement doesnt work and how to make it work

I want to replace javascript code with jquery

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tabell");
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    ...
```

WORKS!!!!

---

```
   var table = $('#tabell').val();
   var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
```

DOES NOT WORK!!!

I get the following error

*11:26:07,810 TypeError: table.insertRow is not a function*

Comment: `insertRow` is a native method, not a jQuery method, so you would have to do `table.get(0).insertRow(-1);`, which sorta defeats the purpose.

Comment: if you need to use jquery then why use `insertRow`?? Use something like `insertAfter / insertBefore`.

Comment: document.getElementById("tabell");  should be $('#tabell') only

Comment: var table = $('#tabell').val();
   var newRow = table.insertRow(-1); instead of this use 
   var newRow = $('#tabell').insertRow(-1);

Comment: pure js you can even do `var newRow = tabell.insertRow(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

The version without jQuery does the following things:

- `var table` = DOMElement with `id="tabell"` (assumed to be a `<table id="tabell">`, though not strictly enforced)
- `var newRow` = `<tr>`-DOMElement

Now, what the jQuery version does is:

- `var table` = an empty string
- `var newRow` throws the error because a string does not have the `insertRow` method.

What you would need to change, is to have jQuery return the `<table>`-element, for example:

```
var table = $('#tabell')[0];
```

or alternatively

```
var table = $('#tabell').eq(0);
```

Though this *assumes* it to always exists, what this does is let jQuery collect the list of elements with `id=tabell` and pick the first one.
If this assumption did work out, the `tabel` variable will contain the DOM-element you're after and `insertRow` will be known.

As you are trying to convert towards jQuery, you may want to rewrite it to something like:

```
var tabel = $('#tabell');
var newRow = table.prepend('<tr>');
```

In which case both `tabel` and `newRow` are - in fact - jQuery wrappings around the matching/created DOM-elements